# Apple Crontab alternative plist to cd a folder and then execute yii script

Tags: macos, yii, plist, cron

I want to recreate this crontab to the new apple plist file to describe and execute a background scheduled job.

The reason I want to recreate this is because crontab has depreciate in OSX and i Had a few background process which were working until i made and update to 10.10.3

> */1 * * * * cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/testdrive/protected/ && ./yiic smssender
>    From the crontab i am navigating to protected folder and then executing ./yiic smsSender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.chapskev.crontabtest</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/al/bin/crontab-test.sh</string>
        </array>

        <key>Nice</key>
        <integer>1</integer>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>

        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>

        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/AlTest1.err</string>

        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/AlTest1.out</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What is the problem? The script doesn't work from plist?

Comment: no i can't re-create it completely, am stuck on navigating to the protected folder, and executing the script using ./yiic smsSender. Am not knowledgeable on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `/Users/al/bin/crontab-test.sh` script should contain the commands you want to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/testdrive/protected/ && ./yiic smssender
```

Remember to set executable flag for `crontab-test.sh`:

```
$ chmod +x crontab-test.sh
```

Set `root` as owner of your `plist` file (the one you posted) and load it as launchd job:

```
$ sudo chown root crontab.plist
$ sudo launchctl bootstrap system crontab-test.plist
```

Comment: Thanks for this let me test it tomorrow am not in the office at the moment